# 0-length file from new :term buffer: vim -c "w! file"

Tags: save

I have a file `mk.out` that contains ANSI codes, which can be cleaned up by opening it in Vim and issuing:

```
:term cat % " Interpret codes in new buffer
:only       " Close source buffer `mk.out`
:w! mk.out  " Overwrite `mk.out` with cleaned up text
```

This works fine, but problems arose when I tried to automate this:

```
vim -c ":term cat %" -c ":only" -c ":w! mk.out" mk.out
```

I am perplexed by the fact that this results in an *empty* buffer for cleaned up code and for `mk.out`.  If I *remove* the command to overwrite `mk.out`, however, the new buffer ends up still containing the cleaned up text, and I can manually issue the overwrite command.

I also tried overwriting to a *different* file `mk.cln` (`cln` is for *clean*).  In contrast to the above, the new buffer for the clean text *doesn't* mysteriously become empty (good), but the written file `mk.cln` is *still* empty:

```
vim -c ":term cat %" -c ":only" -c ":w! mk.cln" mk.out
```

This is regardless of whether the "bang" `!` is present in the write command.  As expected, `mk.out` is not disturbed.  To rule out problems from prompting to overwrite `mk.cln`, I ensured that `mk.cln` did not exist beforehand.

**For `:term`'s new buffer, what would cause the `:write` command to write an empty file when submitted via Vim's `-c` switch, but not when issued interactively?**

---

**Other contextual details**

Writing a new file from an existing file works, but the ANSI codes are not cleaned up:

```
vim -c ":w! mk.cln" mk.out
```

I realize that I need `:wq`, but I'm just trying to troubleshoot for now.

**Vim version**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Mar 30 2020 21:51:17)
Included patches: 1-486
Modified by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Compiled by <cygwin@cygwin.com>
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+browse            +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+channel           +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clientserver      +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+clipboard         +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python/dyn        +visual
+comments          +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+conceal           +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cryptv            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             +sound             -xfontset
+dnd               +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim82"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -D_REENTRANT    -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/vim/vim-8.2.0486-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/vim-8.2.0486-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/vim/vim-8.2.0486-1.x86_64/src/vim-8.2.0486=/usr/src/debug/vim-8.2.0486-1 -fstack-protector-strong -D_REENTRANT  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm    -lncursesw -lcanberra  -liconv -lacl -lattr -lintl   -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.30/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

Comment: I wonder if `%!cat` would work instead of the terminal emulator?

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble: Sorry, I only saw this now.  I gave `:%!cat` a shot, but it preserved the ANSI codes rather than removing them (the latter being the objective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For :term's new buffer, what would cause the :write command to write an empty file when submitted via Vim's -c switch, but not when issued interactively?

You probably need to wait for pending updates.  If so, you need `term_wait()`.

Try this shell command:

```
vim -Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE +'term cat %' +'call term_wait(bufnr("")) | bw! # | w! mk.out | qa!' mk.out
```

If it doesn't work, try to increase the waiting time:

```
vim -Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE +'term cat %' +'call term_wait(bufnr(""), 100) | bw! # | w! mk.out | qa!' mk.out
                                                                       ^^^
                                                                       wait 100ms instead of 10
```

See [:h term_wait()](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_wait()).

---

If `term_wait` doesn't work, success has been had in at least the OP's
case by replacing `call term_wait(bufnr(""), xxx )` with `sleep xxx m`, where *xxx* is the wait time in milliseconds (500 worked for
the OP). The final command can then be shortened to

```
`vim -Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE +':term cat mk.out' +'sleep 500 m | silent! w! mk.out | qa'`.
```

Comment: I tried your 2nd code pattern with 500ms, but everything after physical line 4 is gone in the overwritten `mk.out`. I experimented with writing to `mk.cln`: `vim -c ":term cat %" -c 'call bufnr("")->term_wait(500)' -c ":only" -c ":w! mk.cln" mk.out`. In this case, `mk.out` contains the full unclean file while `mk.cln` contains the top 4 lines. Very odd.

Comment: It works for me when `mk.out` contains [this text](https://0x0.st/i6ts.txt).

Comment: I just saved your test file and tried your 2nd code pattern with 500ms.  The resulting mk.out is an empty file.....thanks for your help.  I'm going to try messing around to see if I can get an idea of what's going wrong.  If I don't figure out within a certain amount of time, I will have to manually intervene in every cleanup.

Comment: I'm not sure why `term_wait` didn't work, but `sleep` seemed to  have worked: `vim +":term cat %" +"sleep 500 m | bw! # | w! mk.out | qa" mk.out`.

Comment: Which Vim version are you using?

Comment: I added the Vim version to the originally posted question. Since I may lose long output from `javac` if my `sleep` is not long enough, I chose to save the cleaned text to a different file than the `javac` output. My final command is `vim +":term cat %" +"sleep 500 m | silent! w! mk.cln | qa" mk.out`. My `Gvim` has a constant window opened on `mk.cln`, and the `silent!` is needed to suppress messages about the swap file existing.

Comment: Try to disable all your configuration; you probably don't need it, and it can badly interfere.  That's why I included `-Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE` in the shell command.

Comment: The following yielded a `mk.cln` that was truncated after 3 lines:
`vim -Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE +':term cat %' +'call bufnr("")->term_wait(500) | silent! w! mk.cln | qa' mk.out`.
The following yielded a `mk.cln` that contained all of the content, cleaned up:
`vim -Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE +':term cat %' +'sleep 500 m | silent! w! mk.cln | qa' mk.out`.
I have to admit, I knew nothing about vim's terminal functionality before this, so I'm ill-equipped to fathom the likely causes.  BTW, *what version of Vim are you using?*

Comment: I'm using Vim 8.2.1634.  I can't help further because I can't reproduce the issue.  Just a guess, but maybe the shell or terminal configuration interferes.  You can start a bash shell without config with `bash --norc --noprofile`.  Although, just to be sure, I would make a test after temporarily commenting out the whole shell and terminal config.

Comment: In the script containing the Vim command, Bash apparently won't allow both switches simultaneously, so I tried each in succession, with the same result. I fell back to `sleep` rather than `term_wait`.
The final version "boldly" cuts out `mk.cln` and so far works with my small `mk.out`:
`vim -Nu NONE -i NONE -U NONE +':term cat mk.out' +'sleep 500 m | silent! w! mk.out | qa'`.
Thanks so much for the investigation that you've done.